# addEventListener click seemingly storing up clicks

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

I've got some javascript code called from an html page. On the html page, I've got a button with an id "button_id". I want the function `DoStuff()` to occur when I click the button, and this bit of javascript achieves this:

```
document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    DoStuff();
}, false);
```

However, when other things are clicked on the html page (and work normally), and I come back to click on the "button_id" button, the `DoStuff()` get executed lots of times. It seems as if the other clicks are getting saved up by this eventListener and all getting released at once.

What's causing this, and how do I solve this problem? BTW, I've been using Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error: http://jsfiddle.net/W33Xh/. Also using Chrome.

Comment: Obviously my actual code has loads of other stuff in it, so I'll try and pare it down until I've turned into the simplest code that reproduces the fault. I tried adding another click to your example code and that didn't generate the fault either.

Comment: Yes, it is likely that the issue is stemming from some other code. Reducing it down should help you zero in on it.